# Oracle Issue with retrieving single row when multiple rows returned

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, cursors

I have a problem that i've spent about 3 days on.

I have a table(CDKEY) with 6 columns: CDKEYSEQ, Userseq,Banned, Communityseq, cdkey,  Email.

Banned is always 0 (at this point), Userseq is NULL unless someone logged on/registered with the cdkey and email is NULL until the cdkey is registered.

Basically Userseq doesn't get filled in until a user logs in. So there will always be an email value before a user sequence value.

NOW The issue:

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that gets called when someone wants a cdkey (which they provide an email for).

The procedure first checks a table called community to make sure the Community exists.

Then if the Community exists The procedure is supposed to check the CDKEY Table for a key that has the correct community sequence AND AlSO has a NULL Value for both USERSEQ and EMAIL.

Obviously using just a select query doesnt work because there are multiple rows that are returned that match those conditions.

I tried using cursors, which got me a little further.
The problem with the cursors is that when I had two conditions after the WHERE clause, it didnt return anything.

Here is my current Procedure Code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE KEYREGISTRATION(
    PRODUCT_IN IN VARCHAR2 ,
    in_CPUID   IN LONG ,
    in_MACID   IN LONG ,
    in_MACID2  IN LONG ,
    in_HDID    IN LONG ,
    in_PCCores IN LONG ,
    in_PCName  IN VARCHAR2 ,
    in_Email   IN VARCHAR2 ,
    out_cdkey OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    returncode OUT NUMBER )
AS
  CodeSuccess       CONSTANT NUMBER := 0;
  CoreError         CONSTANT NUMBER := 2;
  CodeAlreadyExists CONSTANT NUMBER := 3;
  CodeBadProduct    CONSTANT NUMBER := 4;
  new_cdkey         VARCHAR2(50);
  old_cdkey         VARCHAR2(50);
  acommunitySeq     NUMBER;
BEGIN
acommunitySeq := 0;
new_cdkey := '';
old_cdkey := '';
  SELECT COMMUNITYSEQ INTO acommunityseq FROM COMMUNITY WHERE NAME = PRODUCT_IN;
  returncode   := CodeSuccess;
  /*EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      returncode := CodeBadProduct; */
  IF returncode = CodeSuccess THEN
    BEGIN
      SELECT CDKEY INTO old_cdkey FROM CDKEY WHERE EMAIL = in_email;
      returncode := CodeBadProduct;
      out_cdkey  := old_cdkey;
      RETURN;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      returncode := CodeSuccess;
    END;
  END IF;
  IF returncode = CodeSuccess THEN
/*SELECT CDKEY into new_cdkey FROM CDKEY WHERE EMAIL = NULL AND COMMUNITYSEQ = acommunityseq; */
   DECLARE
      CURSOR c1
      IS
        SELECT CDKEY FROM CDKEY WHERE COMMUNITYSEQ = acommunityseq AND EMAIL = NULL;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;
      FETCH c1 INTO new_cdkey;
      IF ( c1%notfound ) THEN
        returncode := CoreError;
      END IF; 
      UPDATE cdkey SET EMAIL = in_email WHERE CDKEY = new_cdkey;
      INSERT INTO user_hw VALUES( EMAIL = in_email, CPUID = in_cpuid,
      MACID = in_macid, MACID2 = in_macid2, CPUCORES = in_pccores, PCNAME = in_pcname;

      out_cdkey  := new_cdkey;
      returncode := CodeSuccess;

      COMMIT;
      END;
  ELSE
    returncode := CoreError;
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
END KEYREGISTRATION;
```

Comment: `EMAIL = NULL` will not work, it must be `EMAIL IS NULL`

Comment: `INSERT INTO user_hw VALUES( EMAIL = in_email, CPUID = in_cpuid,...` is not valid syntax.  It should be `INSERT INTO user_hw VALUES( EMAIL, CPUID, ...) values (in_email, in_cpuid, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You *think* a query will not work - and your reasoning is "because a query will return too many rows." That is incorrect. Add a WHERE clause (or add to the filters you already have), with the condition `ROWNUM = 1` - this will return the first row that meets all the other conditions, the processing will end, and you will get just this row and nothing else.